# How to make a php header never expire?

Tags: php

I want to make a PHP header never expire using:

```
header("Expires: ")
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Just set a datetime in the far future (a year or two is more than sufficient).

Answer (score 6):

```
$now = time( );
$then = gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now + 365*86440);
header("Expires: $then");
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) Section 14.21:

To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an
   Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is
   sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one
   year in the future.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5 version

```
$expires = new DateTime("now + 11 months");
header("Expires:" . $expires->format(DateTime::RFC1123));
```